# Dedicated ToC page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, titles, abstract

Currently I'm using:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,notitlepage]{article}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  body={7in, 10in},
  left=0.75in,
  top=0.5in
}
\begin{document}

%TITLE
\title{Title}

%Authors
\author{
        Author
}
\date{\today}
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}

\maketitle
%ABSTRACT
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\cleardoublepage
%TABLE OF CONTENTS
\tableofcontents
```

I'd like it such that the title and abstract are on one page, and the ToC on a dedicated page directly after.

Comment: What's happening instead, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article class is geared towards compact documents to be published in journals (space is at a premium), you won't be able to get separate title page, ToC, and so on without unbecomming violence. Better consider e.g. report or one of the richer classes, like memoir or the KOMA bundle provided ones.

Comment: Thanks, looking into it report looks to be a much better class.

Comment: @TheRandom, wrong. It isn't a "better" class, it is meant for different types of documents. Both are good for their intended uses but spartan, so many people prefer more full-fledged classes for longer documents.